# How to write to a file in Android (without FileNotFoundException Error)

Tags: java, android

I am having some issues writing to a file in my internal storage in Android. What I am wanting to achieve, is it first of all check whether there is a file (of specified name) already existing in the internal storage. If there isn't, I would then like it to create a file with that name, and write specified content to it. If there is already a file, I would simply like it to write specified content appended to what is already stored within the file. I think I have found how I can check if the file is in existence, and also create a new blank file with the specified name if it isn't (see code below). However, when coming to write to the file I get an error message java.io.FileNotFoundException error, even though my code should ensure that there will always be a file in existence to open with the FileOutputStream. Please could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
public boolean isFilePresent() {
    String strASANo = getIntent().getStringExtra("strASA");  //Part of File Name imported passed from parameter
    String logsFile = strASANo + "logs";
    File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(logsFile);
    return file.exists();
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void addSaveClick(View view) {

if (!isFilePresent()) {
        File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), logsFile);
    }

    FileOutputStream logWriter;
    try {
        logWriter = openFileOutput(logsFile, MODE_APPEND);  //Unhandled Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException


    }

}
```

Comment: Well, if the file is not present, you create a `File` object... and do nothing with it. `new File()` creates a Java `File` object, not a file on the filesystem, if that is what you are thinking.

Comment: Yoy do not have to check if the file already exist. Just open a new FileOutputStream in append mode. Thats all.

Comment: We cannot see the full path you use to create the new file output stream. You should tell us. Tell the value of logsFile.

Comment: You have a try without a catch block. Add it. Put a Toast in it.

Comment: There is no code that writes to the file.

Comment: The FileNotFoundExeption will mention the complete path. You omitted it. Why?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help. Sorry for not providing all the information that would have been helpful - I am new to android programming so not very competent. The filepath I am intending to save to is just the standard internal application directory and the filename is the variable value logsFile. I may be doing this wrong? The FileNotFoundException does not mention a path at all. Do I have to specify a path as well as a filename if I just want it to go to the internal storage path of the app?